# How to access Token in next-auth?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, next-auth, next.js13

I want to implement my credentials login logic.
The problem is i can't access token in `useSession` hooks.
I need token to send it to backend for `REST API's` endpoints.
I searched a lot, read a lot and even asked ChatGPT but nothing worked for me.
This is my implemention

pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts;

```js
import NextAuth, { AuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import { getProfile } from 'utility/api/audience';

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        token: { label: 'Token', type: 'text' },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        if (!credentials?.token) return null;
        const token = credentials.token;

        const { profile } = await getProfile(token);

        if (profile)
          return {
            email: profile.data.email,
            name: profile.data.fullName,
            id: profile.id,
            token,
          };
        else return null;
      },
    }),
  ],
};
export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

In callback object I printed a lot of `console.log` but none of the parameters included token. just the email and name and some timestamp.

I will appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of search and trying everything, I finally found something that worked.

For those who want to achieve the same result as me just simply pass this callback in `[...nextauth].ts`

```
export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        token: { label: 'Token', type: 'text' },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
         const token = credentials.token || '';
        if (!token) return null;

        const { profile } = await getProfile(token);

        if (profile)
          return {
            ...profile,
            token,
          };
        else return null;
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: { //  =====> Add Below Callbacks <=====
    jwt: async ({ token, user }) => {
      return { ...token, ...user };
    },
    session: async ({ session, token }) => {
      session.user = token;
      return session;
    },
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
};
```

Now useSession hook will return every data you pass it.

NOTE: If your using typescript you can create a ts file in `types/next-auth.d.ts`

and overwrite the Session Type like this

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth/next';

declare module 'next-auth' {
  interface Session {
    user: {
      name?: string;
      token?: string;
      email?: string;
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: yup that's correct